# reader_container_right command is missing under elements section in Dev Tools? Is there a way to locate this? cant locate this under chrome Firefox

Tags: python, java, c#, html, xcode

I am clicking on a webpage and then clickin on inspect or source page and need to locate this command "reader_container_right". I am using different browsers such as chrome, firefox and microsoft edge. However, it is missing under "elements" section in Web Dev Tools.

I need this command to copy some text in the fastest possible.

Thanks

I tried different browsers such as firefox, microsoft edge and chrome. But somehow I can not locate "reader_container_right command" under elementnts tab in devlopment tools in order to copy text from the website page.

I need this command to copy paste on htmltools.com/editor to copy text in the fastest possible.

However, I can not locate this command under these browsers